# C++ class definition split into two headers?

Tags: c++, class, header-files, partial-classes

Is it possible in C++ to split the definition of class members in two headers? What would be the appropriate way to code it?

For instance:

a1.h

```
class A {
    public:
        int var;
        void foo1(int b);
}
```

a1.cpp

```
#include "a1.h"

void A::foo1(int b) {
    cout << b;
}
```

a2.h

```
[extend] class A {
    public:
        void foo2(double c);
}
```

a2.cpp

```
#include "a2.h"

void A::foo2(double c) {
    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing much you can do past PImpl other than Microsoft's partial classes extension (unless I'm remembering wrong and there's no C++ support for those at all).

Comment: This is not possible with standard C++. Which problem is it you want to solve with this technique? Maybe we can help you with that problem? :)

Comment: @Magnus Hoff It's for a class that gets modified often. Keeping the methods that are being worked on in a saparate .cpp and .h would allow for fast compilation of that ofent changing code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't extend a `class` that way, but you can use the `pimpl` pattern:

```
class A {
public:
    void foo1(int b);
private:
    AImpl* pimpl;

}
```

and then have `AImpl.h` and `AImpl.cpp` that hides all the private details.

Comment: So Aimpl.h and AImpl.cpp would have foo2() and the header of class A should include AImpl.h ? how would foo2 be implemented in AImpl.cpp?

Comment: @Davinish no, you can't add public members like that, maybe you should look at inheritence for extending a `class`